# How to enable cursor move while using readonly attribute in input field in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

How to enable cursor move while using readonly attribute in input field in chrome browser, working fine with firefox.This is to observe the full value in the input box which will not be editable.Knowing the fact that this is a browser dependent feature, any other way to overwrite this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theres a really good reason that Chrome doesn't let the cursor blink in a read only text box and that is because a blinking cursor indicates that a user can type in that control.

So first up its worth deciding from a UX point of view if you want to go against that principle!

If you really really do, you could fake a read only behaviour by using a custom `data-` attribute to specify that you want the input to be read only and then just ignore any non-navigational keypresses.

```
var allowedKeys = {
    "37" : "arrow-left",
    "38" : "arrow-up",    
    "39" : "arrow-right",    
    "40" : "arrow-down",
    "9" : "tab",    
    "27" : "esc"        
}

$("input[data-readonly=readonly]").keydown(function(e){
    console.log(e.which);
    if (!allowedKeys[e.which]) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

You can take a look at the fiddle here.  http://jsfiddle.net/BUcC2/1/

If your intention is for this to be a normal input control that should behave in a standard way, I would recommend not using this method and stick with the browser's interpretation of the best way to display html :)

Comment: @Vignesh yes this is my requirment

Comment: Can you point to some source for the usability principle you mention ? Based on my current understanding a blinking cursor does not indicate editability, it indicates that one can meaningfully move the cursor in the text, and while a possible reason for moving the cursor is certainly editing, another perfectly valid one is selecting. Since _readonly_ input fields do allow selection (which is probably the main reason why they exist alongside _disabled_ ones) I think they should show the cursor. The fact that the user can't change the content is rendered by other UI aspects.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with Google chrome, as you can't set the cursor to move in an input field when it is Read-Only, but in IE and firefox it is possible.

Comment: Good point and also Safari does show the cursor. And so do VisualBasic readonly textboxes and all textboxes I can think of in Windows if you set them as readonly. So far Chrome is the only place - browser or desktop app - where I ever saw a readonly input field allowing selection but not showing the cursor. I think it should be considered a bug, also because if you first select one char with the mouse, after that the usual Shift+[direction keys] work and you can continue selecting that text with the keyboard.